# Python Class is not working with sorted function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and i was reading python documentation and in given example on http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions i am stuck and i am not getting how it exactly working.

I am using eclipse Pydev to run this code ..

```
class Student:

    student_object = [
                  ('john', 'a', 15),
                  ('as', 'C', 12),
                  ('dave', 'B', 10)
                  ]

    def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.age = age


    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.name, self.grade, self.age))



print sorted(Student.student_object, key=lambda Student: Student.age)
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\workspace\demPython\src\ru.py", line 26, in <module>
    print sorted(Student.student_object, key=lambda Student: Student.age) 
  File "C:\Users\user1\workspace\demPython\src\ru.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    print sorted(Student.student_object, key=lambda Student: Student.age) 
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'age'
```

How class and method works in python ?? Why this code is not working ??

**EDIT**

> But i changein last line and replace with given line

```
print sorted(Student.student_object, key=lambda student: student[0])
```

it is working and giving me output `[('as', 'C', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('john', 'a', 15)]`

Comment: You have mixed up the examples from the docs; re-read them more carefully. `student_tuples` is completely separate from the class-based example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because the items in `student_object` are not instances of your `Student` class, they are just normal tuples. That's why the error is `'tuple' object has no attribute 'age'`.

You need to create the student objects first:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0.name} {0.grade} {0.age}'.format(self)

students = [Student('john','a',15), Student('as','C',12), Student('dave','B',10)]
print sorted(students, key=lambda x: x.age)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no field called `age`, in your `student_object` . So you need this

```
print sorted(Student.student_object, key=lambda Student: Student[2])
```

Alternatively, you can use `itemgetter` like this

```
from operator import itemgetter
getage = itemgetter(2)
print sorted(Student.student_object, key = getage)
```

**Note:** Don't name your variables with initial capital letters.

Comment: But there is field age ?? `self.age = age`

Comment: @KumarDharm But you are trying to sort, `student_object` only, right?

Comment: +1 for the *note section* - Important advice as this is standard practice defined in the PEP

Comment: @KumarDharm: There is not. The items in student_objects are tuples, not Students, which basically means they have no more structure than any other list, and you get information out of them like you would a list: if `x = ('John', 'A', 15)`, then `x[2]` is the correct way to get the number 15 back. This answer covers one possible solution where you abandon the Student class altogether and just manage your data with tuples. For other solutions, which involve leaving tuples behind and managing your data with the Student class, see the other answers.

Comment: @OwenS. I got your answer and understood what i was doing wrong. I was using just tuples and it had nothing to do with class. If i want to use class i have to make object too.

this kind of response on very simple question i have never seen, i am so thankful to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Student.student_object` is just

```
student_object = [
              ('john', 'a', 15),
              ('as', 'C', 12),
              ('dave', 'B', 10)
              ]
```

and has nothing to do with the Student class, except that it is "inside" it. Something like

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.age = age


    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.name, self.grade, self.age))



student_object = [ Student('john', 'a', 15),
                   Student('as', 'C', 12),
                   Student('dave', 'B', 10) ]


print sorted(student_object, key=lambda x: x.age)
```

instead, would, since each element of the array is a Student instance, so the age attr is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Classes define the structure and behavior of objects, aka instances. When you define a class, `Student`, like you do here, Python creates a function `Student()`, called an initializer, that you can use to create instances of that class. Since you provided an `__init__` method for Student, Python will arrange to invoke that as the implementation of the initializer.

So, to create a Student object, you will need to invoke Student's initializer with the arguments specified by your `__init__` method. For example: `Student('john', 'A', 15)`.

Your key function (i.e. the anonymous function you created with the `lambda` expression) expects to receive something with an `age` property. Presumably that's supposed to be an object which is an instance of the Student class. However:

1. Naming a parameter as `Student` is simply incorrect. Student does not refer to the class here; it is just like any other function parameter, and simply gives a name to the argument you will be receiving in this function. Note that, unlike some languages, you don't have to mention both the type name and the variable name when you declare a parameter in Python; you just declare the variable name and start using it. Also note that it is very bad Python style to name variables starting with capital letters, for just this reason: it confuses people as to what are variables, what are classes, etc.
2. The objects actually being passed to your key function are not Students. Since you invoke `sorted()` on a list of tuples, the items your function receives are tuples, which you can think of as instances of a built-in `tuple` type that Python provides.

So, first focus on getting a list of Students, and understanding exactly how creating objects works. Once you do that, calling `sorted` on it like you have done will work. Then, fix your key function to use a lowercase `student` parameter for sanity's sake, and you're good to go!